Can't display images properly after changing file paths in Tkinter when changing pages
So I'm making an app for school, and I want to change pages when I press a button, but when the button is pressed, the page display properly. Only the text is appearing, but none of the images or buttons. I think the problem is in the s_carbin, but I just can't seem to figure it out. I'm pretty new to coding in general, so apologies if the answer is obvious.
from pathlib import Path
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Button, PhotoImage

OUTPUT_PATH = Path(__file__).parent
ASSETS_PATH= OUTPUT_PATH / Path(r"C:\Ayden\Sigayon\build\assets\frame0")



window = Tk()
window.geometry("540x960")
window.configure(bg="#FFFFFF")

def relative_to_assets(path: str) -> Path:
    return ASSETS_PATH / Path(path)

def clear_page():
    print ("page cleared")
    


def s_welcome():
    clear_page()


    canvas = Canvas(
        window,
        bg = "#FFFFFF",
        height = 960,
        width = 540,
        bd = 0,
        highlightthickness = 0,
        relief = "ridge"
    )
    canvas.place(x = 0, y = 0)
    canvas.create_rectangle(
        0.0,
        0.0,
        540.0,
        960.0,
        fill="#FBFBFB",
        outline="")

    canvas.create_text(
        29.0,
        312.0,
        anchor="nw",
        text="Beauties of Sagay",
        fill="#2E2E2E",
        font=("Poppins SemiBold", 30 * -1)
    )

    button_image_1 = PhotoImage(
        file=relative_to_assets("button_1.png"))
    button_1 = Button(
        image=button_image_1,
        borderwidth=0,
        highlightthickness=0,
        command=s_carbin,
        relief="flat"
    )
    button_1.place(
        x=31.0,
        y=360.0,
        width=138.75,
        height=47.25
    )

    button_image_2 = PhotoImage(
        file=relative_to_assets("button_2.png"))
    button_2 = Button(
        image=button_image_2,
        borderwidth=0,
        highlightthickness=0,
        command= None,  
        relief="flat"
    )
    button_2.place(
        x=179.5,
        y=360.0,
        width=138.75,
        height=47.25
    )

    canvas.create_text(
        30.0,
        97.5,
        anchor="nw",
        text="Welcome to Sagay",
        fill="#2E2E2E",
        font=("MontserratRoman SemiBold", 36 * -1)
    )

    canvas.create_rectangle(
        0.0,
        0.0,
        540.0,
        75.0,
        fill="#7FC21E",
        outline="")

    button_image_3 = PhotoImage(
        file=relative_to_assets("button_3.png"))
    button_3 = Button(
        image=button_image_3,
        borderwidth=0,
        highlightthickness=0,
        command=lambda: print("button_3 clicked"),
        relief="flat"
    )
    button_3.place(
        x=465.0,
        y=7.0,
        width=62.0,
        height=61.0
    )

    canvas.create_rectangle(
        -2.0,
        73.0,
        540.0009155273438,
        75.0,
        fill="#3F3F3F",
        outline="")

    canvas.create_text(
        26.0,
        15.0,
        anchor="nw",
        text="Sigaiyon",
        fill="#FFFFFF",
        font=("Poppins SemiBold", 40 * -1)
    )

    canvas.create_text(
        82.5,
        179.25,
        anchor="nw",
        text="Popular",
        fill="#FFFFFF",
        font=("RobotoRoman Medium", 27 * -1)
    )

    button_image_4 = PhotoImage(
        file=relative_to_assets("button_4.png"))
    button_4 = Button(
        image=button_image_4,
        borderwidth=0,
        highlightthickness=0,
        command=lambda: print("button_4 clicked"),
        relief="flat"
    )
    button_4.place(
        x=30.75,
        y=158.25,
        width=236.25,
        height=60.0
    )

    button_image_5 = PhotoImage(
        file=relative_to_assets("button_5.png"))
    button_5 = Button(
        image=button_image_5,
        borderwidth=0,
        highlightthickness=0,
        command=lambda: print("button_5 clicked"),
        relief="flat"
    )
    button_5.place(
        x=31.5,
        y=225.75,
        width=236.25,
        height=60.0
    )

    button_image_6 = PhotoImage(
        file=relative_to_assets("button_6.png"))
    button_6 = Button(
        image=button_image_6,
        borderwidth=0,
        highlightthickness=0,
        command=lambda: print("button_6 clicked"),
        relief="flat"
    )
    button_6.place(
        x=275.25,
        y=225.75,
        width=236.25,
        height=60.0
    )

    button_image_7 = PhotoImage(
        file=relative_to_assets("button_7.png"))
    button_7 = Button(
        image=button_image_7,
        borderwidth=0,
        highlightthickness=0,
        command=lambda: print("button_7 clicked"),
        relief="flat"
    )
    button_7.place(
        x=274.5,
        y=158.25,
        width=236.25,
        height=60.0
    )

    button_image_8 = PhotoImage(
        file=relative_to_assets("button_8.png"))
    button_8 = Button(
        image=button_image_8,
        borderwidth=0,
        highlightthickness=0,
        command=lambda: print("button_8 clicked"),
        relief="flat"
    )
    button_8.place(
        x=30.0,
        y=419.0,
        width=479.0,
        height=421.0
    )

    button_image_9 = PhotoImage(
        file=relative_to_assets("button_9.png"))
    button_9 = Button(
        image=button_image_9,
        borderwidth=0,
        highlightthickness=0,
        command=lambda: print("button_9 clicked"),
        relief="flat"
    )
    button_9.place(
        x=318.0,
        y=328.0,
        width=63.0,
        height=21.0
    )

    window.resizable(False, False)
    window.mainloop()

def s_carbin():
    clear_page()
    global ASSETS_PATH
    ASSETS_PATH = OUTPUT_PATH / Path(r"C:\Ayden\Sigayon\build\assets\frame3")
    print("ASSETS_PATH:", ASSETS_PATH) 

    canvas = Canvas(
        window,
        bg="#FFFFFF",
        height=960,
        width=540,
        bd=0,
        highlightthickness=0,
        relief="ridge"
    )
    canvas.place(x=0, y=0)

    canvas.create_rectangle(
        0.0,
        0.0,
        540.0,
        960.0,
        fill="#FBFBFB",
        outline=""
    )

    canvas.create_text(
        28.0,
        468.0,
        anchor="nw",
        text="Carbin Reef",
        fill="#2E2E2E",
        font=("MontserratRoman SemiBold", 48 * -1)
    )

    canvas.create_text(
        31.0,
        566.0,
        anchor="nw",
        text="And, you are not a being who should die. Your people need the future. Thank you. I'm glad I met you. [for a long, long moment, Shinji and the EVA hold still, as Kaworu looks up at them. Then, the fist closes with a loud crush]  Singing is great. Singing enriches the soul. It's the crowning achievement of the civilization that the Lilim created. Don't you feel the same? Ikari Shinji-kun?",
        fill="#3A3A3A",
        font=("MontserratRoman SemiBold", 24 * -1)
    )

    button_image_1 = PhotoImage(
        file=relative_to_assets("button_1.png"))
    button_1 = Button(
        image=button_image_1,
        borderwidth=0,
        highlightthickness=0,
        command=lambda: print("button_1 clicked"),
        relief="flat"
    )
    button_1.place(
        x=15.0,
        y=15.0,
        width=56.0,
        height=56.0
    )

    button_image_2 = PhotoImage(
        file=relative_to_assets("button_2.png"))
    button_2 = Button(
        image=button_image_2,
        borderwidth=0,
        highlightthickness=0,
        command=lambda: print("button_2 clicked"),
        relief="flat"
    )
    button_2.place(
        x=30.0,
        y=840.0,
        width=480.0,
        height=90.0
    )

    image_image_2 = PhotoImage(
        file=relative_to_assets("image_2.png"))
    image_2 = canvas.create_image(
        270.0,
        440.0,
        image=image_image_2
    )

    canvas.create_rectangle(
        180.0,
        530.0,
        214.0,
        564.0,
        fill="#ECECEC",
        outline="")

    canvas.create_text(
        220.0,
        535.0,
        anchor="nw",
        text="40  C",
        fill="#7E7E7E",
        font=("RobotoRoman Medium", 20 * -1)
    )

    canvas.create_text(
        244.0,
        533.0,
        anchor="nw",
        text="o",
        fill="#7E7E7E",
        font=("RobotoRoman SemiBold", 10 * -1)
    )

    canvas.create_rectangle(
        31.0,
        530.0,
        65.0,
        564.0,
        fill="#ECECEC",
        outline="")

    canvas.create_text(
        74.0,
        536.0,
        anchor="nw",
        text="30 mins",
        fill="#7E7E7E",
        font=("RobotoRoman Medium", 18 * -1)
    )

    image_image_3 = PhotoImage(
        file=relative_to_assets("image_3.png"))
    image_3 = canvas.create_image(
        48.0,
        547.0,
        image=image_image_3
    )

    image_image_4 = PhotoImage(
        file=relative_to_assets("image_4.png"))
    image_4 = canvas.create_image(
        197.0,
        547.0,
        image=image_image_4
    )


s_welcome()




I changed the asset path to the coresponding folder in the s_carbin function, but it's not displaying the images or buttons'

Yes it doess. TYSM
